# Getting date from a query which is not showing exact as entered in table

Tags: ms-access

I want to get MAX purchase date from a query.

I have written code which can show date in message box. But problem is that the date is not showing exactly as entered in the table. In the table date is 11-04-17, but in the message box date is shown 30-12-99.

My Code is:

```
Dim dbforPurdate As Database
Dim rsforPurdate As Recordset

Dim vmedid As String
Dim dtpurtbl As Date
Dim Qryfordate As String

vmedid = Me.MedID
Set dbforPurdate = CurrentDb
'Qryfordate = "SELECT Purchaset.[Purchase Date] AS PurDate, PurchaseDetailt.[Receipt No], PurchaseDetailt.MedID, PurchaseDetailt.BatchNo FROM Purchaset INNER JOIN PurchaseDetailt ON Purchaset.[Receipt No] = PurchaseDetailt.[Receipt No]"

Set rsforPurdate = dbforPurdate.OpenRecordset("Qryfordate")
dtpurtbl = Nz(DMax("[Purchase Date]", "qryfordate", [MedID] = "'" & vmedid & "'"), 0)

MsgBox Format(dtpurtbl, " dd/mm/yy ")
```

Comment: Domain aggregate functions do not work on VBA recordsets, they work on table and query objects. Do you have a query object named qryfordate? Why are you opening a recordset?

Comment: Yes, I have object named qryfordate. without opening recordset I also didn't get correct result. 
Is there any solution?

Comment: Opening a recordset in VBA has no bearing on performance of domain aggregate function.

Comment: Please tell me its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DMax() is not finding a value which returns Null and therefore the Nz() returns 0 and the Format() function converts 0 to 30-12-99.

The DMax() shows syntax errors and I am surprised you do not get runtime error. It is missing quote mark in front of [MedID] and has an extra quote mark after = sign.

Is MedID really a text type field?

`DMax("[Purchase Date]", "qryfordate", "[MedID] = '" & vmedid & "'")`

If you want the message box to not show the funky date value:

`MsgBox IIf(dtpurtbl = 0, "No Date", Format(dtpurtbl, " dd/mm/yy "))`

Comment: Thank you so much june7.